# wc_countries - states selection dropdown - woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am struggling to set up a form with a default WooCommerce country and states selection dropdowns.

Basically, I want to show Country selection and then state selection based on the country selection. So if the user chooses UK, the new dropdown with states selection will show.

I got as far as this:

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$countries_obj   = new WC_Countries();
$countries   = $countries_obj->__get('countries');
$default_country = $countries_obj->get_base_country();
$default_county_states = $countries_obj->get_states( $default_country );

echo '<div id="ships_from_countries_field">' . __('Countries') . '';

    woocommerce_form_field('my_country_field', array(
           'type'       => 'select',
           'class'      => array( 'chzn-drop' ),
           'label'      => __('Item ships from - country'),
           'placeholder'    => __('Select a Country'),
           'options'    => $countries
            )
     );
 echo '</div>';

 echo '<div id="ships_from_state_field">' . __('States') . '';

     woocommerce_form_field('my_state_field', array(
            'type'       => 'select',
            'class'      => array( 'chzn-drop' ),
            'label'      => __('Item ships from - state'),
            'placeholder'    => __('Select a State'),
            'options'    => $default_county_states
             )
      );
  echo '</div>';
  ?>
```

Countries dropdown is displaying countries and states dropdown displaying states of the shop base - UK

But how do I make them work together and save the values?

Cannot find any info, anybody has any experience making this work?

Comment: I'm confused, to be honest.  WHY do you think you have make this happen? WooCommerce does this out of the box - is this a custom form? Or what page are you doing this on?

Comment: How do I implement the default WC functionality then? Would you be able to point me to the right direction? I was trying to replicate the checkout page and get it from there, but that just seems a little too confusing. This code is the only thing I found after days searching on how to get the country and state selection working ..

Comment: What page are you doing this on? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Its one of my other plugins template page. This plugin offers editing the product from front-end.
On this page I need to place a country selection dropdown and state selector dropdown.

Answer (score 11):

first of, there's a type for country and state.. you don't need to do much... it's just like this...

```
echo '<div id="ships_from_countries_field">' . __('Countries') . '';

    woocommerce_form_field('my_country_field', array(
       'type'       => 'country',
       'class'      => array( 'chzn-drop' ),
       'label'      => __('Item ships from - country'),
       'placeholder'    => __('Select a Country')
        )
    );
echo '</div>';

echo '<div id="ships_from_state_field">' . __('States') . '';

    woocommerce_form_field('my_state_field', array(
        'type'       => 'state',
        'class'      => array( 'chzn-drop' ),
        'label'      => __('Item ships from - state'),
        'placeholder'    => __('Select a State')
        )
    );
echo '</div>';
```

take note of their type... they're not of type select.

now on your problem..

**PHP**

you need to have localized script for country and state... I won't go on how to use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). Read the link if you need to. Here's a part of it.

```
$wc_country = array(
    'country' => json_encode( array_merge( WC()->countries->get_allowed_country_states(), WC()->countries->get_shipping_country_states() ) )
);
wp_localize_script( 'my-js', 'my_js', $wc_country );
```

**javascript**

with that, in your `my-js` script (a script file) you can read the state like this:

```
    var states_json = my_js.countries.replace( /&quot;/g, '"' ),
        states = $.parseJSON( states_json );
```

you then have to add a change event on your country and repopulate state based on what country was selected...

example: `states["PH"]` if country selected is Philippines

```
00: "Metro Manila"
ABR: "Abra"
AGN: "Agusan del Norte"
AGS: "Agusan del Sur"
AKL: "Aklan"
ALB: "Albay"
ANT: "Antique"
APA: "Apayao"
AUR: "Aurora"
BAN: "Bataan"
BAS: "Basilan"
BEN: "Benguet"
BIL: "Biliran"
.....
WSA: "Samar"
ZAN: "Zamboanga del Norte"
ZAS: "Zamboanga del Sur"
ZMB: "Zambales"
ZSI: "Zamboanga Sibugay"
```

you can then build your options like this using jQuery..

```
var options = '',
    state = states[ country ]; // country can be: var country = $('country').val();

for( var index in state ) {
    if ( state.hasOwnProperty( index ) ) {
        options = options + '<option value="' + index + '">' + state[ index ] + '</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Reigel, I really, really appreciate your help on this .. I've been looking all around for a solution, I'll get onto it and post back the result .. many thanks again for taking your time ..

Comment: this one must be marked as accepted answer. you have given not just the idea, but a complete solution :)

Comment: var states_json = my_js.countries should be like var states_json = my_js.country

Answer (score 0):

I looked how woocommerce did it in checkout. Instead of making my own js I just included the js they already made and the included the data in the same format they use.

```
        $suffix  = ( defined('SCRIPT_DEBUG') && SCRIPT_DEBUG == 'TRUE' ) ? '' : '.min';
        // $version = Constants::get_constant( 'WC_VERSION' );
        $jsUrl = plugin_dir_url( 'woocommerce').'woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/country-select' . $suffix . '.js';


        //add in scripts to handle state dropdown on country selection
        $wc_country = array(
                'countries' => json_encode( array_merge( WC()->countries->get_allowed_country_states(), WC()->countries->get_shipping_country_states() ) )
        );
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" id="wc-country-select-js-extra">';
        echo ' /* <![CDATA[ */';
        echo 'var wc_country_select_params = '.json_encode($wc_country).';';
        echo '/* ]]> */';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$jsUrl.'"></script>';
```

Comment: This code works but I still haven't got the code for getting the URL to javascript quite right. how should I use plugin_dir_url and version?