# WooCommerce Country Selection on Registration

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to add the default country searcher from WooCommerce to the registration page, while a default list of countries is possible with the following code snippet:

```
<?php
$countries_obj  = new WC_Countries();
$countries      = $countries_obj->get_allowed_countries();
woocommerce_form_field('billing_country',array(
'type'      => 'select',
'class'     => array('chzn-drop'),
'label'     => __('Country'),
'placeholder' => __('Choose your country.'),
'options'   => $countries,
'required'  => true,
'clear'     => true
));
?>
```

It's of course not the same as the original country select from WooCommerce, so I was wondering if anyone knows the right way to add this Country Selection field to the registration page.

Edit: if I understand it correctly, you would require to load a JavaScript library for the dropdown to work properly, how would someone load this onto the registration page exactly AND how would someone set the default country for example to 'Belgium'?

Edit2: Seems it has something to do with this part of script for the Country Selector:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//uklederwaren.be/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/country-select.min.js?ver=2.6.14'></script>
```

Not exactly sure how to add this exactly to the registration page as I'm sure it has something to do with a loop of the allowed countries and what not, so any help would be appreciated!

Edit3: I found an answer of one of my side questions how I would be able to set the default country and this could be done by adding the 'default' => 'XX', in the woocommerce_form_field array. The XX stands for the country code, so for Belgium this would be BE.

Thanks in advance for further information.

TL;DR:
[image]

Conclusion: The problem was solved with both the help of HelgaTheVviking and Raunak Gupta, where my currently full code for the whole registration page including all the sections (and a custom vat page) is the following:

```
/* ---------------------- Registration page ----------------------- */
//Add extra fields in registration form
add_action('woocommerce_register_form_start','my_extra_register_fields');
function my_extra_register_fields(){
?>
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e('First Name','woocommerce'); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if(! empty($_POST['billing_first_name'])) esc_attr_e($_POST['billing_first_name']); ?>"/>
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e('Last Name','woocommerce'); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if(! empty($_POST['billing_last_name'])) esc_attr_e($_POST['billing_last_name']); ?>"/>
    </p>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_billing_company"><?php _e('Company Name','woocommerce'); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_company" id="reg_billing_company" value="<?php if(! empty($_POST['billing_company'])) esc_attr_e($_POST['billing_company']); ?>"/>
    </p>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_billing_vat"><?php _e('VAT Number','woocommerce'); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_vat" id="reg_billing_vat" value="<?php if(! empty($_POST['billing_vat'])) esc_attr_e($_POST['billing_vat']); ?>" maxlength="15" placeholder="Enter VAT Number"/>
    </p>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
    wp_enqueue_script('wc-country-select');
    woocommerce_form_field('billing_country',array(
        'type'        => 'country',
        'class'       => array('chzn-drop'),
        'label'       => __('Country'),
        'placeholder' => __('Choose your country.'),
        'required'    => true,
        'clear'       => true,
        'default'     => 'BE'
    ));
?>
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="reg_billing_postcode"><?php _e('Postcode / ZIP','woocommerce'); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_postcode" id="reg_billing_postcode" value="<?php if(! empty($_POST['billing_postcode'])) esc_attr_e($_POST['billing_postcode']); ?>"/>
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="reg_billing_city"><?php _e('Town / City','woocommerce'); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_city" id="reg_billing_city" value="<?php if(! empty($_POST['billing_city'])) esc_attr_e($_POST['billing_city']); ?>"/>
    </p>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_billing_address_1"><?php _e('Address','woocommerce'); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_address_1" id="reg_billing_address_1" value="<?php if(! empty($_POST['billing_address_1'])) esc_attr_e($_POST['billing_address_1']); ?>" placeholder="Street address"/>
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_address_2" id="reg_billing_address_2" value="<?php if(! empty($_POST['billing_address_2'])) esc_attr_e($_POST['billing_address_2']); ?>" placeholder="Apartment,suite,unit etc. (optional)"/>
    </p>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e('Phone','woocommerce'); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php if(! empty($_POST['billing_phone'])) esc_attr_e($_POST['billing_phone']); ?>"/>
    </p>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
}
//Registration form fields Validation
add_action('woocommerce_register_post','my_validate_extra_register_fields',10,3);
function my_validate_extra_register_fields($username,$email,$validation_errors){
    if(isset($_POST['billing_first_name']) && empty($_POST['billing_first_name'])){$validation_errors->add('billing_first_name_error',__('A first name is required!','woocommerce'));}
    if(isset($_POST['billing_last_name']) && empty($_POST['billing_last_name'])){$validation_errors->add('billing_last_name_error',__('A last name is required!','woocommerce'));}
    if(isset($_POST['billing_company']) && empty($_POST['billing_company'])){$validation_errors->add('billing_company_error',__('A Company name is required!','woocommerce'));}
    if(isset($_POST['billing_vat']) && empty($_POST['billing_vat'])){$validation_errors->add('billing_vat_error',__('VAT number is required!','woocommerce'));}
    if(isset($_POST['billing_country']) && empty($_POST['billing_country'])){$validation_errors->add('billing_country_error',__('A country is required!','woocommerce'));}
    if(isset($_POST['billing_city']) && empty($_POST['billing_city'])){$validation_errors->add('billing_city_error',__('A city is required!','woocommerce'));}
    if(isset($_POST['billing_postcode']) && empty($_POST['billing_postcode'])){$validation_errors->add('billing_postcode_error',__('A postcode is required!','woocommerce'));}
    if(isset($_POST['billing_state']) && empty($_POST['billing_state'])){$validation_errors->add('billing_state_error',__('A state is required!','woocommerce'));}
    if(isset($_POST['billing_address_1']) && empty($_POST['billing_address_1'])){$validation_errors->add('billing_address_1_error',__('An address is required!','woocommerce'));}
    if(isset($_POST['billing_phone']) && empty($_POST['billing_phone'])){$validation_errors->add('billing_phone_error',__('A phone number is required!','woocommerce'));}
    return $validation_errors;
}
//Below code save extra fields when new user register
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer','my_save_extra_register_fields'); 
function my_save_extra_register_fields($customer_id){
    if(isset($_POST['billing_first_name'])){
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'first_name',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']));
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'billing_first_name',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['billing_last_name'])){
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'last_name',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_last_name']));
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'billing_last_name',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_last_name']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['billing_company'])){
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'billing_company',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_company']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['billing_vat'])){
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'billing_vat',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_vat']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['billing_country'])){
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'billing_country',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_country']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['billing_city'])){
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'billing_city',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_city']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['billing_postcode'])){
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'billing_postcode',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_postcode']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['billing_state'])){
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'billing_state',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_state']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['billing_address_1'])){
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'billing_address_1',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_address_1']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['billing_phone'])){
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'billing_phone',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_phone']));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        update_user_meta($customer_id,'billing_email',sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']));
    }
}
```

I thank everyone who helped me in this process and with my previous questions as well, the whole project of mine is almost coming to an end so I really have to thank the Stackoverflow Community for their great support!

Comment: Are you adding one field with WooCommerce Reg while checkout or WordPress Registration form itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934028/using-the-woocommerce-api-to-get-the-country-state-lists

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757408/wc-countries-states-selection-dropdown-woocommerce

Comment: @Mujeebu Rahman

As stated I'm using this on the registration page, not on the checkout page. 
The related questions you've posted is where I got the above code from, but that doesn't really answer my current question to how to format the country selection box to the default style/status of what WooCommerce has.

My main question is to format the country drop down to the default as WooCommerce, the default selection (to Belgium) is optional and not my main concern.

Comment: I've found an answer to my side question regarding the default country already, this can be archived by using: 'default' => 'BE'. Either way thanks for your input! Now in hopes to solve the main question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `woocommerce_form_field()` function supports a `country` type, so I think this could work:

```
/**
 * Add new register fields for WooCommerce registration.
 */
function wooc_extra_register_fields() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-country-select' );

    woocommerce_form_field( 'billing_country', array(
        'type'      => 'country',
        'class'     => array('chzn-drop'),
        'label'     => __('Country'),
        'placeholder' => __('Choose your country.'),
        'required'  => true,
        'clear'     => true
    ));

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );
```

**Edit** You need to enqueue the country select script in order to get the JS-assisted drop-down.

Comment: Hi there once again HelgaTheViking! Thanks for your reply, however changing the type to country did not change anything to the appearance I'm afraid, the look still remained the general appearance like the left side of the image in my main post. This is the page url in case that helps in any kind of way: https://uklederwaren.be/my-account/

Comment: Your URL is under construction. But I've discovered that you need to enqueue the country select script. See my edit. This is working for me, though it may not be *where* you wish to display the field.

Comment: Yea the URL was only public for around 3 hours after I posted it, as it's still a site that shouldn't be made public, I could only hold it open for 3 hours after the post I made, I wanted to mention this but I couldn't edit my post anymore.

That said, I did try your code snippet hover that didn't work exactly as no field appeared at all. I also thought about enqueuing the script myself, but even adding the script code in the default header, didn't gave the desired effect.

The now accepted answer with the JS code snippet did work for me however. Still I thank you a lot for you assistance!

Comment: Well that's a shame, because this is the better answer since it relies on more built-in features of WooCommerce instead of duplicating them. You may need to test whether you have a `woocommerce_register_form_start` hook (though that hook is 4 years old) because [here is my outcome](https://d.pr/9Sa93) with WC3.0 and a default theme.

Comment: Hmm that's actually quite strange, I did try variations of your code as I'm already hooking into the registration field to add all other fields, so I just added the code without the function and add action to the part where I required it. But nevertheless the field didn't even show up. Not sure if this is something to do with the other code I'm currently using or my current WooCommerce 2.6.4 version (but that shouldn't be the case).

I'll look into it further, perhaps something was indeed interfering with it and report back if I get this to work, if it does I even might change the acceptance

Comment: Alright, so I've isolated the problem and brought all the code I had to a separated plugin, which in the end made your code work. I've got no clue to why it wouldn't work in the functions.php, maybe I missed something or overlooked it when I tried your code and the variations.

But with that said, I do completely now see why this would be a better answer by using the built-in features rather than the jquery snippet.

Therefore I will change the accepted answer as this might be useful for future people, and while I can't provide you the points of the bounty anymore, I'm still very thankful!

Comment: I appreciate the diligence!

Comment: Also, the value I enter on Registration field (see pokerdiy.com signup) is not saved in the usermeta table ->  billing_country field. If I edit the profile after sign in and update it in my profile then I can see it saves. I am using WC email verification - the account is created but they have to verify their email. Any idea why billing_country is not saved to DB? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> If you see the source HTML of WooCommerce Checkout page then you will
>   see it uses [**`select2`**](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic-control) JS plugin. So you need to pass a extra
>   ID/class in [`woocommerce_form_field()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#1841-2061) then called select2 JS
>   function, in footer.

So your full code would be

```
//to add billing_country
function wh_extra_register_fields()
{
    $countries_obj = new WC_Countries();
    $countries = $countries_obj->get_allowed_countries();
    woocommerce_form_field('billing_country', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'input_class' => array('myClass'), //<--check this line
        'label' => __('Country'),
        'placeholder' => __('Choose your country.'),
        'options' => $countries,
        'required' => true,
        'clear' => true,
        'default' => 'BE' //<--check this line
    ));
}

add_action('woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wh_extra_register_fields');

//to add js code in My Account page footer
function wh_AccountPageJS()
{
    if (is_account_page())
    {
        echo '<script>jQuery(".myClass").select2();</script>';
    }
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'wh_AccountPageJS', 100);
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.** *version 3.0.*

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this worked for me! I also first thought that it had to be something enqueued to it like the script I found, but that didn't work either. But the script snippet you've provided worked directly. So thanks for the assistance and with this you've got the bounty and marked as valid ;) 

Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: @RafaëlDeJongh: I have used select box jQuery plugin in past, so I knew I have to initialized that. btw I'm glad that it worked for you, and in return I also got to learn how to customized registration page.

Comment: Thanks once again, future investigation with the code from HelgaTheViking did manage to work as well, and as it uses more built-in features of WC I therefore will accept her answer now as valid. But do know that your code worked for my the first, while I did had some trouble implementing the other code.

Either way I gratefully thank you for your help and assistance!

Comment: Hi @RaunakGupta, how do I add this to the AJAX registration page too (I have it working on the my-account page), but most logins are on the pop.

Comment: Also, the value I enter on Registration field (see pokerdiy.com signup) is not saved in the usermeta table ->  billing_country field. If I edit the profile after sign in and update it in my profile then I can see it saves. I am using WC email verification - the account is created but they have to verify their email. Any idea why billing_country is not saved to DB? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the template/function:

```
<?php
$field = [
        'type' => 'country',
        'label' => 'Country',
        'required' => 1,
        'class' => ['address-field']
];
woocommerce_form_field( 'billing_country', $field, '' );
$field = [
    'type' => 'state',
    'label' => 'State',
    'required' => 1,
    'class' => ['address-field'],
    'validate' => ['state']
];
woocommerce_form_field( 'billing_state', $field, '' );
?>
```

Include woocommerce country-select.js at page with the form:

```
<?php
    $handle = 'wc-country-select';
    wp_enqueue_script($handle, get_site_url().'/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/country-select.min.js', array('jquery'), true);
?>
```